# Effect of perturbation on Perron eigenvalues

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let the entries of a $n \times n$ non-negative matrix be perturbed by a small amount so that the new matrix remains non-negative. I am interested in knowing how the Perron eigenvalues of the perturbed matrix will differ from that of the original.

Comment: So, what sort of Perron eigenvalue behavior you want to know? Asymptotics?

Comment: It moves (Hölder) continuously in general, but better if the matrices are strictly positive. Is this your case? Or you want the most general setup?

Comment: @Evgeny@H.H.Rugh: Can you please give me some reference so that I can read it properly.

Comment: @Evgeny: Pl. see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have a good reference on perturbations of PF eigenvalues but it is fairly simple to make examples. For $\epsilon\geq 0$:
$$ M_\epsilon = \left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1\\ 
\epsilon & 0 & 1\end{matrix}\right) $$
has char pol $p(\lambda)=(\lambda-1)^3-\epsilon\ $ so the leading eval is $\lambda=1+\epsilon^{1/3}$, i.e. is  $\frac{1}{3}$-Hölder continuous in $\epsilon$.

In dimension $d$ you may at worst get $\frac{1}{d}$-Hölder.

It can not get worse simply because you look at zeroes of a polynomial with coefficients that are polynomials in matrix elements. A root of order $d$ behaves $1/d$-Hölder continuously in the matrix elements and an isolated zero depends analytically upon the matrix.

In particular, from this you also see that in the strictly positive case, the leading eval is isolated (PF-theorem) so behaves analytically with the matrix.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation

Comment: Another related question: Suppose we have two non-negative matrices $A$ and $B$ and $\|A-B\|$ (operator norm) is very small. What can we say about the absolute value of the difference between the PF eigen values of $A$ and $B$. Are there literature on this ? Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have any literature about general PF perturbations. If you take my first example $\epsilon$ is a bound on the operator difference. So the bound is like $\|A-B\|^{1/3}$ in that case. If you change the upper two $1$'s to large constants then you will even have a large prefactor. If all elements are strictly positive then more can be said (as the PF evalue is then solated). If you have a more specific problem then perhaps tell about it?